# VLC Plugin for Chrome stop playing in the middle of video

Tags: google-chrome, vlc

I am working on a webapp to upload and show video.
I deploy the webapp on 2 `glassfish app servers`. One on `Windows`, the other on `Centos`.
On both deployments, I can upload and play a video

But, when I call the webapp from `Centos deployment`, the vlc plays only half of the video.

I don't know what went wrong.

Comment: maybe this can shed some light: I got this error message in a log file: org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.blockAfterWriteIfNeeded(OutputBuffer.java:951)

Answer (score 0):

ok, I have solved the problem. The log message gave great hint.
The cure is to enlarge the timeout amount on glassfish setting.

On the glassfish remote administrator:
Configurations --> server-config --> Network config --> Protocols --> http-listener-1

click the 'HTTP' tab, change the value of timeout from 30 to 200.